# macOs Fonts are web safe?

Tags: html, css, macos-sierra, font-family

Pages app in mac has a long list of fonts. Can I use these fonts on my web page by specifying **font-family="xyz"**? 
What I want to know is the fonts used in mac apps like pages,numbers 
are proprietary and unique or they are common fonts that will be available and supported on most devices?

Comment: "So pages has a long list of fonts" — Pages has a list of fonts **installed on your computer**. We don't know what fonts you've installed. We have no way of knowing the statistics for how many people have them installed.

Comment: I have the default list of fonts that come installed with mac! And basically thats my question! How many of these fonts are common... I mean that will come bundled with major pc and mobile os? And how can I manually include a new font in my website which is installed by default on my mac?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.  Are you asking how to include a font on your webpage?  If so, you use [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).  If you're trying to serve a font that is provided by Apple to users that may not necessarily be using Macs, don't.  You'll likely get into copyright issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest approach will always be to use a web font from google fonts or a font that you have directly in your website so browsers can download it always directly from the website. 
If you just call for a font that is installed in the pc like Times New Roman (that both windows and mac generally have) the website probably will work on both windows and mac, but on linux clients it probably won't work, you can do that but you need to set a fallback font just in case they client doesn't have that specific font.

And when you add mobile to the list it gets even worst, generally android has sans droid, or some other propriatary fonts that PCs just don't have unless they are directly installed.

And even IF the browser tried to make up for the lack of font, it might apply a font that doesn't work too well with your website and end up making some pretty weird formatting issues, and if the OS itself has a font with the same type family and it just applies that one you could end up with the same problem, but generally it probably will just show up all as squares/rectangles.